# Pattern/Best practice for updating objects on server from multiple clients

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a general question about a best practice or pattern to solve a problem.

Consider that you have three programs running on seperate JVMs: Server, Client1 and Client2.

All three processes make changes to an object. When the object is changed in either client, the change in the object (not the new object) must be sent to the server. It is not possible just to send the new object from the client to the server because both clients might update the object at the same time, so we need the delta, and not the result.

I'm not so worried about reflecting changes on the server back to the clients at this point, but lets consider that a bonus question.

What would be the best practice for implementing this with X amount of processes and Y amount of object classes that may be changed?

The best way i can think of is consistently using the Command pattern to change the object on the client and the server at the same time, but there has to be a better way?

Comment: observer design patter tha you can use for this kind of problem

Comment: Is it possible to use the observer pattern over a network? And usually i see the observer pattern used to notify about a change, not specifically what changed?

Comment: The actor model comes to mind, as it is already message based. So replecating the message to the other servers should be easy. Take a look at Akka.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible ways to solve that is the [Remote Method Invocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) system in Java. Keep all the data values on the Server, then have the clients use remote calls to query them.

This would however require some smart caching to reduce the amount of pointless calls. In the end you would end up with something similar to the Command Pattern.

Modern games try to solve this issue with something I'd call an Execute-Then-Verify pattern, where every client has a local copy of the game world, that allows him to come to the same conclusion for each action as the server would. So actions of the player are applied to the local copy of the game world assuming that they are correct, then they are sent to the server, which is the ultimate instance to either accept that or revoke it later on.

The benefit of this variant of local caching is, that most players do not experience much lag, however in the case of contradictory actions they might experience the well-known roll-backs.

In the end it very much depends on what you are trying to do and what is more important for you: control over actions or client action flow.

Comment: Would you say that the Execute-Then-Verify pattern, as you call it, would be somewhat equal to executing a command on a local copy and the server copy, and then later polling the server for the "Actual" result?

Comment: There are similarities, but the difference is that the Server can respond with a simple ACK or not send any data at all to the executing client, to keep the overhead as low as possible. It could as well just forward the action to the other clients and have them decide on their own what's going to happen. A some points the server will have to do a full update, but the target is to keep that as seldom as possible. So in this case the server is only a verification instance, not an actual actor.

Comment: So the client would send an update, and the server would then accept or reject it, and the client would then do nothing, or rollback?

But then what happens if another client makes a change, would the server then just send the change, or the entire object, to the other clients?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. In game worlds many actions are negligible and it doesn't matter if the client is mistaken. If you have business control software, this might be an entirely different situation. So you can basically classify those as critical and not critical changes. The unimportant ones would just be forwarded as "Client X did this: ..." and the critical ones would include the actual new state of the world. In addition more or less frequent updates need to ensure that the error of local worlds does not exceed a certain grade.